# How to add text on top of a textarea element

Tags: html, jquery, textarea, element

I have a textarea element with some messages on it and a button.
When I click the button It adds more text on it but the thing is that the text is adding at the bottom of the textarea and I want it added on top of it.

This is my code:

```
$('#textarea_id').append("New text added");
```

Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how to do it with just js.  Get the original text and then append that to your new text.  Finally, set the innerHTML of the textarea

```js
let ta = document.getElementById('ta')

let s="some more text to append to top. "

ta.innerHTML= s + ta.innerHTML
```

```css
#ta{
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='ta'>This is some text at the top</textarea>
```